# Pandas in operator to extract rows based on multiple values in dateframe columns

Tags: python

I used `in` operator to extract rows from the input as shown below but getting error message at the bottom. Can someone figure out why I am getting an error?

```
Date AgeGroup Gender Count
2048-09-30 50-54 M 1000 
2048-09-30 55-59 F 1200 
2048-09-30 55-59 M 1300 
2048-09-30 60-64 F 1400 
2048-09-30 60-64 M 1500 
2048-09-30 65-69 F 1600 
2048-09-30 65-69 M 1700 
2048-09-30 70-74 F 1890 
2048-09-30 70-74 M 1500 
2048-09-30 75-79 F 1320 
2048-09-30 75-79 M 1100 
2048-09-30 80-84 F 1240 
2048-09-30 80-84 M 2000 
2048-09-30 85+ F 1730 
2048-09-30 85+ M 1800
```

```
AGEGE65F = df.loc[(df['Gender']=='F') & (df['AgeGroup'] in ('65-69','70-74','75-79','80-84','85+')]

File "<ipython-input-86-4920f0add248>", line 23
    AGEGE65F = df.loc[(df['Gender']=='F') & (df['Age Groups'] in ('65-69','70-74','75-79','80-84','85+')]
                                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Missing `)` near end.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of the `in` operator within the `loc` is incorrect. You should `isin` and its argument should be a list as shown under -

```
AGEGE65F = T1L.loc[(T1L['Gender'] == 'F') & (T1L['AgeGroup'].isin(['65-69','70-74','75-79','80-84','85+'])]
```

Comment: I tried 'isin' but still got the same invalid syntax error message.

Comment: all brackets properly closed??